# ORA-12154 Oracle DB Windows Can't Connect SQLPlus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have checked the other answers in stackoverflow but didn't work any of it. I checked the tnsnames.ora there is no error I can find. This the code of my tnsnames.ora file.

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-69D6TBS)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-69D6TBS)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

This is my sqlnet.ora

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

Service is also running

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As is so often the case when this very question comes up, you did not show the initial command you used to start sqlplus.   You should start it like this, following your username with an '@' sign, followed by the net service name, aka tnsnames entry.

```
c:\sqlplus myuser@XE
```

But lacking that, once it start prompting you for username and password, you need to follow the prompted username with with the spec for the net service name:

```
Enter user-name:  username@XE
```

But the fact that you got that particular error is a bit puzzling.  Without specifying the net service name, it should have attempted a BEQ connection (not using tns at all) to connect to a local database identified by the value of %ORACLE_SID%.  IN that case it should either connect or give a "protocol adapter error"  The fact that it got this particular error in this particular usage would indicate to me that you have %TWO_TASK% set.  This overrides ORACLE_SID and tells sqlplus to attempt a tns connection for the value of %TWO_TASK%.

As a side note, the nature of the reported error means the request never got anywhere near a listener, so the listener config is of no concern at this point.  ORA-12154 is the equivalent of not being able to find someone's name in the telephone book. If you can't find it (it's unlisted or you are using the wrong telephone book) then you can't even place the call (send the request to the listener).

And for future reference, screen shots of command windows are not as helpful as copying and pasting the text from the window, then formatting the pasted text as 'code'.  If you had done that here, you could have scrolled the window up so as to copy/include the sqlplus command you used.

Comment: I connected to db using SQLPlus. it is created when installed the oracle db

Comment: @Shenald Please launch a Windows CMD shell or a PowerShell. From there type: C:\>sqlplus system/<my_password>@XE You will now connect to the CDB. (root-container). All your user objects (tables,indices,functions, etc..) will go into the pluggable database XEPDB1. You can connect to it like this: sqlplus system/<password>@XEPDB1 .. if you add this entry to the tnsnames.ora file SERVICE_NAME=XEPDB1  Paste the output into your question. Please do not upload any screenshots of the results. We only like output in text format so we can utilize the browsers search function and of course copy & paste.

Comment: @EdStevens , Completely agree, but on Windows Oracle uses the %local% environment variable. I would suggest unsetting it completely when actual local connections are desired. `set local=`

Comment: @AndrewSayer - yep, I work mostly with LInux and always forget that on Windows the variable is %LOCAL%.

Comment: "I connected to db using SQLPlus. it is created when installed the oracle db –"  And how does that statement address _any_ of the questions you were asked or points that were raised?  We know that sqlplus is created when you install the db. We know that you were _attempting_ to use it to connect to the database.

Comment: One note to the above comments is that the user appears to be trying to connect as SYS, so no doubt needs to use AS SYSDBA.  If this is all on one machine then maybe `sqlplus / as sysdba` will work, but I haven't used Windows for decades.

Comment: @BjarteBrandt I have added my tnsnames.ora file into qustion. I have try your method also but now working. 
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: "I have try your method also but now working. ORA-12154:"  And what was the result of 'sqlplus / as sysdba'.  As for the 12154, I've raised several points on that and you have yet to respond to any of them.